# Someone deleted several of my answers, and I don't know why

Tags: discussion

How do I contact someone in StackOverflow? For example someone deleted my post and I don't understand why. How would I ask this person (the moderator)? I click on them but don't see any contact information? Should I just ask them why underneath the comment that was deleted even though it has nothing to do with the subject of the original question?

Answer (score 21):

All of your deleted answers are really comments or attempts to engage in conversation.  Stack Overflow doesn't work like that.

When you click the "Post Your Answer" button, we expect you to be answering the question that was asked at the top of the page, not engaging in dialog with other users or making observations such as *"I have the same problem."*  Those kinds of answers do not help anyone.

The fact that you asked this question in the wrong place is further evidence that you don't understand how the site works.

Before you post anything else on Stack Overflow, please read:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: the site also explicitly tells you that answers are not for discussion when you first answer

Comment: Finally figured out the right way to do this. I wanted to write this in the "Add Comment" section of the post. When I went here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955307/linkmovementmethod-causes-editing-issue-in-edittext and tried to use the "Add Comment" section but I don't see this feature. I also did not see this feature mentioned in any of the reading you recommended. I also didn't see the Meta StackOverflow forum mentioned in your reading either (or even how to find it, I searched for it but found nothing).

Comment: @user1438489: You need 50 reputation points to gain the privilege of posting comments to other people's posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: Also didn't see any documentation saying when something should go on Meta StackOverflow vs. regular StackOverflow. This answer seems inaccurate because I have seen "dialog with other users" being engaged using the "Add Comment" section like we are doing right now. In fact, virtually every post I have ever seen has this back and forth dialog. Is this something that everyone is doing wrong on StackOverflow?

Comment: Thank you @user1438489. That make a lot more sense to me now.

Comment: Why does my question have a -3 ranking? It is a legitimate question. Why does the one answer have a 21 even though it is wrong? Robert Harvey's response on the July 26 is the correct answer. You can't have a back and forth session without either having 50+ reputation or starting your own question.

Comment: I don't know why you think this answer is wrong.  You are correct that you can't post comments without 50 rep, but you also can't engage in a discussion using answers as a proxy for comments.  We require 50 rep for comments because Stack Overflow is primarily about getting answers to questions, not engaging in discussion.  Comments exist primarily for clarification, not conversation.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: I do agree that having answers that simply state "I have the same problem" are very annoying, but having a dialog is not. In fact it is because of the dialog that my question got answered at all by @user1438489. Most people would agree that knowing the answer is much easier than knowing the right question to ask. A push to discourage discussion is a push toward ignorance. If you disagree I would suggest reading through some of the older StackOverflow questions and counting how many were better resolved/understood because of discussion. The number may surprise you.

Comment: That being said I do like the way StackOverflow has comments take a less prominent role. Many times people just want an answer so this format is one of the best (but it still has discussion).

Comment: @AaronKlap: Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86496