# Is there a policy about removing "Thanks" from posts?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I understand posts don't *need* any fluff to them and just the questions, which is why I try and avoid any salutations or "autobiographies"; though I don't think adding a simple thanks to the end of the question hurts and many people like to thank the people that will read the question and possibly help them in advance.

This is a site filled with *user* content and whilst I understand editing the posts to make them more readable/easier to understand, doing unnecessary edits is just rude.

With that said, my question is, is this site policy?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: 1.  This is a site for feedback and support, not the posting of rants.  2.  Stack Exchange is designed to be the antithesis of all of those crappy forums.  If you like the way forums work, use a forum.

Comment: My first down vote - "thanks" for that. Ooh.... another just came in!! :D Let's see how many I get.

Comment: @mystical Thanks ;) But I've seen those, still felt the need to post my own thoughts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you notice the question? ;) I like SE and forums, though find forums a LOT more friendly.

Comment: And I find forums a lot more useless.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has edited the "thanks" out of his post yet.

Comment: I wonder though, are "rouge thugs" really into their make-up or did you mean "rogue"?

Comment: @Bart That would be correct, feel free to edit it though, as I say, that's fine. :) That's a valid reason for editing. ;)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Forums generally take longer to get a response on and have a lot less knowledgeable people, though you don't have to think before you do every little thing that someone is going to get "up in arms" about it and vote to close your question, down vote or edit your post just to make themselves feel powerful.

Comment: Your questions are sufficiently elaborate, so a small addendum doesn't disturb. You can keep the "Thanks!". I'll allow it. -- Generally it's an empty phrase. Most editors remove it because newcomers use it equivalent to "Thanks in advances for the codez, suckers" on postings with limited prior research etc. Which is why "Thank you" has fallen from grace.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I dislike forums as much as anyone, but SE does have a [forum component](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/venn-diagram.png), so to speak.

Comment: @Bart the OP could have been referring to any of a number of -- often extremist and/or violent -- political groups that use rouge, or the local language's equivalent, in their names. See (e.g.) the Khmer Rouge and Brigate Rosse. EDIT: on the other hand, the OP could leave a comment indicating that you were right about the typo while I was looking up the correct spelling of Brigate Rosse.

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86496

Comment: @PopularDemand Once again I stand corrected. I might make a personal feature request where all  my comments and other contributions first have to get your personal approval. I am sure we would all like to prevent me from making any such embarrassing mistakes in the future. Either that or I might even consider having my account deleted. The shame...the shame...

Comment: @Brett I would undo that rollback. That edit made your question (for however much it is one) more constructive. I won't get into an edit war with you, but in its original form there's not much constructive content there. Perhaps you can edit it yourself.

Comment: This argument has been done to death.  The answer is always the same: Anything that doesn't contribute to answering a person's question is noise.  If you really want to thank someone, upvote and accept their answers.  Better yet, pay it forward by answering the questions of others.  If you still feel compelled to immortalize your politeness, do it in a comment, not in a post.

Comment: @Bart I see where you're coming from, but my main point of this "question" was to relay how I felt and I didn't feel the edited version relayed that, so I rolled it back. I see this "question" is closed now as I pretty much expected it to be, SE really is a very unfriendly community, which is a shame as there are a lot of knowledgeable people here.

Comment: The knowledgeable people are here because they don't have to deal with the cruft that's present in those other forum environments.

Comment: SE is a pretty friendly community actually. It just doesn't tolerate non-constructive rants very well. Especially here on Meta. A better phrased question would have still been closed as a duplicate, but might possibly have seen far fewer downvotes and criticizing comments.

Comment: @Bart, I honestly can't tell if I've made you angry, or confused, or amused, or what.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No Robert, the knowledgeable people are here because the site has a good concept and is really the only one of it's kind. Not everyone is unfriendly, though a large portion are.

Comment: There is a substantial minority of the community that confuses friendliness with "I can do anything I want here,"  and unfriendliness with "you edited/closed my post."  It is misguided.  For the most part, they are people who don't understand why SE is designed the way it is.

Comment: @PopularDemand Hahahaha, I see my sense of humour doesn't translate well. Don't worry. I'm not easily offended to begin with and don't see why your comment should have offended me. Just a bit of harmless fun. ;)

Comment: Some things to bear in mind - 1--Once you post it here it doesn't belong to you any more.  2--Some people may see it as hypocritical that you complain about "unfriendliness" while essentially calling everyone who fixes your posts an egotistical maniac.

Comment: Would you expect a Wikipedia article to end with "you're welcome"? If not, then your posts here shouldn't end with "thanks". This site is *a reference* for future users with the same question and your questions and answers should read like *reference*. Unrelated preamble about your experience/current situation, salutations, signatures, tagline, "thanks in advance", chat speak and emoticons have *no place* in your questions and answers. If you want to thank somebody, up-vote them or accept their answer.

Comment: @meagar "Would you expect a Wikipedia article to end with "you're welcome"?" That's probably the single best way I've heard this explained.

Comment: @BenBrocka Dear Sir: Thanks :) -- meagar

Comment: @JNK Ummm yes it still does belong to me, according to the FAQ contributions here are licensed under the creative commons license, SE doesn't take over copyright to the content that users create.

Comment: @Brett Once it's posted by you on the site, it can be freely edited as per the licensing agreement.  You don't have any more rights to it than anyone else at that point, except that you can request removal of attribution.

Comment: @meagar Don't post a stupid analogy; whilst this site is an educational tool it is a question/answer site first and foremost. So to answer your question, no I wouldn't expect to find "thanks" at the end of a Wikipedia article for the simple fact that it doesn't contain any questions.

Comment: @JNK My original content I still have rights to, you can edit it, but I still retain the rights to my original content; so again, going back to your point in that "Once I post something, I don't own it anymore" is still false.

Comment: @Brett You can continue to argue the point if  you like.  The version posted here belongs to the site in perpetuity essentially.  You still own rights to it as well but you can't for instance demand that they remove it because it doesn't reflect your original intent any longer.

Comment: @Brett If you take the time to **read** my analogy, you'll note that I said "you're welcome", not "thanks". The analogy is very apt, as you would know if you'd bothered to gain a little experience on Stack Overflow before posting this rant. Stack Overflow is a **collaboratively edited wiki reference**. It's stated purpose is to be a *work of reference*, in the exact same way that Wikipedia is meant to be a work of reference. Your questions and answers should mirror Wikipedia for formal tone and writing style.

Comment: @Brett I am quoting from the FAQ when I say: "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you". You do not own your posts. Your posts become property of the community and people are no only welcome to edit them, they are encouraged to do so. If you won't accept this you cannot post here.

Comment: @JNK You can argue as much as you like as well; I can't argue they remove it if it's been edited, but I do have the right to have my name removed from it.

Comment: @meagar You actually said "You're welcome" and "Thanks". ;)

Comment: @Brett. No, I didn't. Please **read my comment**. *"Would you expect a Wikipedia article to end with "you're welcome"? Then your posts **here** shouldn't end with "thanks".* I never said or implied that wikipedia articles should/shouldn't include "thanks". I specifically sidestepped that counter-argument, but you made it anyways except now your counter-argument doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @meagar My mistake. Sorry. Though, putting "You're welcome" in a Wikipedia article or a QUESTION on here wouldn't make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 12):

This discussion isn't new. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Everybody seems to agree that salutations and taglines should be removed (in fact, most salutation get removed automatically), but the community is a little more divided on the "thanks".

Personally, I think it should be removed, although an edit to do that and only that might not be worth it. It's unnecessary fluff. It makes sense if you think of the question as something personal, but the main purpose of your question and its answers is helping future visitors.

If you want to thank somebody, just use votes.

Comment: If you end every single one of your questions with "Thanks in advance!", how is that not a tagline?

Answer (score 12):

I think you're overblowing the problem*.  First, I looked through every one of your posts. Here's what I found:

As of this writing you've asked **128** questions. Exactly **7** of them had the "Thanks" edited out (in its various forms). What's funny is that of those 7 edits, only **2** *weren't* substantial edits.

What this tells me that during the course of improving your questions, some editors are editing out the "Thanks!" to make the question in line with Stack Overflow standards.  This may upset you, but that's how we do things here. That's what keeps us separated from mere forums.

Substantial Edits:

- [Uploadify Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4072889/revisions)
- [OSCommerce / Zencart / Cubecart, which is easier to consume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184092/oscommerce-zencart-cubecart-which-is-easier-to-customize)
- [Get Amount of Rows when doing a MySql INTOFILE query](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5929968/revisions)
- [InfiniDB options: how to set them?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6091295/revisions)
- [Writing Valid HTMLText Areas? cannot leave out rows and cols?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5363227/revisions)

Non-substantial Edits:

- [Absolute Positioning and Its Parent Element](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11862330/revisions)
- [What happens when putting UTF-8 data into a latin1 database column?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10460441/revisions)

If I include **all** questions you've asked across **all Stack Exchange Sites**, that only raises the total up another **5**. You've had a grand total of **12 out of 157** questions edited to remove the *Thanks!*, and in the vast majority of those cases, the OP also made other edits that made the question better than it was before.

---

* This is a feature, not a problem. I wish more people took the time to edit other people's posts into shape. So yes, there's a problem, it's just not the problem you are bringing up.

Comment: Disagree about the second being non-substantial; 3 different pieces of fluff were removed making the post a lot less annoying to read. It also passes the "is there anything left to edit" test

Comment: @BenBrocka I mostly agree, except that I tend to weigh edits a lot differently than most people.  If you look at my edits, you'll understand why. I tend to reduce, simplify, and rewrite a lot of the posts I edit.

Comment: You're missing questions from other SE sites. Most noticeably one where the editor played "edit wars" with me to keep taking it out a couple of times.

Comment: @Brett Engaging in a Rollback war is not a Good Thing To Do.  Generally moderators will warn both users, lock the question, and drive on.  It's not worth getting in a rollback war over.

Comment: @Brett I looked at all your questions across all sites, across all SE sites besides Stack Overflow, you've had *5* out of 29 questions edited to remove the thanks. Again, I don't think there's a lot going on here, and even so; they made your question better.